# NSDictionary is treated as a boolean - can't debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

```
NSDictionary *tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *card = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
        [[UserAccount sharedInstance] cardNumber],
        [tokenData objectForKey:@"CardPhoneToken"]]; //<-- problem
});
```

I've been fighting with this line of code since yesterday.I'm geting a JSON feed from the server nad My problem is that one time out of ten `tokenData` returns with `0` instead of a `Dictionary` and I can't figure out why. When it returns as `0` it is also treated as a boolean by the compiler (can't figure out why either) and i'm getting the error `-[NSCFBoolean objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81aa20`

I've tried doing something like this 
`if(!tokenData)
                {
                    NSLog(@"This is going to crash");
                }` But when `tokenData` returns `0` the `if` isn't getting called.

esponseDict JSON I'm getting :
`{ code = 200; data = {
        multipass =         {
            CardPhoneBarcodeToken = 562431;
            CardPhoneToken = 23221;
            errorMessage = "";
            operationResult = 0;
        };
    };
}`

This is how it looks right before it crashes: `{ code = 200; data = { multipass = 0; }; }`

**Update:** I've managed to take action if `tokenData` is not `NSDictionary` now I'm facing another problem with the `else` section. How can I reload the tokenData if it's not a `NSDictionary` ? I tried calling *tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"]; inside the else but I'm keep getting tokenData = 0
Thanks

Comment: can you please psot the json or can you please NSLog the responseDict

Comment: Is the `multipass` object also a dictionary? It seems you are pulling out an `NSNumber` out of the `data` dictionary.

Comment: This is how it looks right before it crashes:  `{
    code = 200;
    data =     {
        multipass = 0;
    };
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check if `tokenData` is a `NSDictionary` before parsing it.

```
-(void)loadData
{
    NSDictionary *tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *cardPhoneToken = @"";
        if( [tokenData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ){
            retryCount = 0;
            cardPhoneToken = [tokenData objectForKey:@"CardPhoneToken"];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"failed to load data, retrying...");
            retryCount++;
            if( retryCount < 5 ){
                [self loadData];
                return;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"failed after 5 retries");
            }

        }
        NSString *card = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
                          [[UserAccount sharedInstance] cardNumber],
                          cardPhoneToken];

    });
}
```

Comment: Your code works, thanks but now I'm facing another problem with the `else` section. How can I reload the `tokenData` if it's not a `NSDictionary` ? I tried calling `*tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"];` inside the else but I'm keep getting `tokenData` = 0

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a retry function. I used a NSInteger retryCount; for it.

Comment: That way of reloading the input data from the web service would work, if you can really expect the response to change. If it is rather random "1 out of 10", as you say, for any reason, then relaoding may help. If the 0 is returned at that point for reasons in the underlying data or whatever, that you cannot expect to change within seconds, then this approach would just waiste time by repeating the same thing over and over until you eventually have to deal with the situation anyway.

Comment: Hermann has a good point here. You might want to investigate or contact the webservice owner, to see why it is returning 0

Comment: I'm getting 
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x8900107f) when trying to [self myMethod];`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds familiar. :)

Change the block to:

```
^{
    NSString *card;
    if ([tokenData isKindOfClass [NSDictionary class]) {

      card = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
          [[UserAccount sharedInstance] cardNumber],
          [tokenData objectForKey:@"CardPhoneToken"]]; // <<-- No Problem anymore
     } else {
       // deal with the situation. Probably do: 
      card = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@-no phone number given", [UserAccount sharedInstance] cardNumber]];
}
```

Alternative:

```
^{
    id cardPhoneToken;
    if ([tokenData]) {
       cardPhoneToken = [tokenData objectForKey:@"CardPhoneToken"];
    } else {
       cardPhoneToken = @"no Phone Token"; // Or what ever you think is appropriate
    }
    NSString *card = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
        [[UserAccount sharedInstance] cardNumber],
        cardPhoneToken]; // <<-- No Problem anymore

}
```

Comment: As you can see in my updated question when I find that `tokenData` is not a `NSDictionary` I need to handle it. My question is, how do I "reload" `tokenData` to get the `NSDictionary`? Should I call `NSDictionary *tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"];` again? maybe inside a `while` to make sure it's a  `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: When I try to do something like this: `while (![tokenData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                    {
                     tokenData = [[responseDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"multipass"] ;
                    }` I'm getting the error `Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)`

Comment: You cannot reall "reload it", because there is not associative array (= dictionary) within your JSON input at that very point. You will have treat this as an exception somehow. You may 'fake' a dictionary by assigning one. But that may not help much, I guess.

Comment: Re your second comment. The while loop that you suggest will be certainly run for ever. Unless, maybe, the content of the NSDictionary is changed within by another thread. But that would still not be any kind of smart design.